# How to show MySQL query results using PHP in box-style?

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli, styles

I'm setting up a new Website and i want to show the results of a searching MySQLi query in boxes.

My php code....

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `products`");
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))    {
      echo "<img src='/Images/".$row['product_image']."' height='200' width='200'>"
      echo '<h6> Id:'.$row['product_id'].'</h6>';
      echo '<h6> Name:'.$row['product_name'].'</h6>';
      echo '<h6> Proce:'.$row['product_price'].'</h6>';
                                               }
```

With that code the results of a searching query are presented like this

[image]

I'm trying using with many ways to achieve a presentation of the results like this way:

[image]

Any idea or advice? Thank you

Comment: a html table, would be the easiest option

Comment: @tim I try with HTML but i cant handle well the array[] from the query and how to connect properly HTML and PHP [id the searching button is pressed]

Answer (score 0):

**Use css "float: left"**

```
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `products`");
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))    {
          echo '<div style="float:left">';
          echo "<img src='/Images/".$row['product_image']."' height='200' width='200'>";
          echo '<h6> Id:'.$row['product_id'].'</h6>';
          echo '<h6> Name:'.$row['product_name'].'</h6>';
          echo '<h6> Proce:'.$row['product_price'].'</h6>';
          echo '</div>';
                                                   }
```

Comment: this will just create one long row

Comment: And it should adapt to the screen size with auto breaking use css margin-left and margin-right to make them spare apart from each others.

Comment: Thank it works but the style that i had disappear (for example the background color i had)... How to solve this?

Comment: Use css classes instead of inline styling and then assign all properties needed

Answer (score 0):

you can use **bootstrap** to achieve this. For example, just add class="col lg-4" inside the div tag, and you will have 3 columns for each row.

Sample code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="content">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <?php
      $get = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `product_name`");
          
      while ($products = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) { ?>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="thumbnail" align="center">
            <img src="admin/images/products/<?php echo $products['photo']; ?>" style="width: 220px; height: 150px">
            <div class="caption">
              <h4>
                <?php echo $products['product_name']; ?>
              </h4>
              <span>$<?php echo number_format($products['price']); ?></span>
              <br />
              <br />
              <a href="index.php?data=detail&i=<?php echo $products['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</a> &nbsp;
              <input type="button" name="wishlist" id="add_wishlist" value="+ " onclick="addWishlist('<?php echo $products[id]; ?>', '<?php echo $id_user; ?>')" class="btn btn-info">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```